# Libreoffice theme integration not working (Xubuntu)

Tags: 11.10, libreoffice, xubuntu

I am running Xubuntu 11.10 and everything works nicely. I have selected a nice Xfce theme and everything looks beautiful, except Libreoffice.

While other programmes (Gimp, Inkscape, Thunar etc.) integrate with the selected Appearance & Window Manager theme, Libreoffice looks like a Windows 98 programme.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I have already tried this solution, without success: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1584010&page=2

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @fossfreedom: no. It uses something called vcl.

Comment: @RolandTaylor - ta - nice to know :)

Comment: Same problem and same solution as in accepted answer encountered in Ubuntu Studio 15.10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ensure that you have [libreoffice-gtk](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libreoffice-gtk) installed, if not it will not be integrated correctly. LibreOffice is a vcl application (not sure if any other applications use that toolkit), and needs packages like that for integration with GTK+ and Qt.

Comment: Hi Roland, thanks a lot! This answered my question. Installed libreoffice-gtk and now it looks wonderfully. But not sure why this was not installed on default. I installed Libreoffice through the Ubuntu Software Centre.

Comment: @Treepata: it doesn't seem to get pulled in by default (for some reason libreoffice does not depend on it), so you have to manually add it later.

Answer (score 0):

I directly downloaded .tar.gz package from official libre office website and followed instruction in readme file. its pretty easy and theme works fine.

Comment: This does not provide a sufficient answer to the question. Try to add more information, and / or examples.